# How to disable or hide contact and comment option from the dashboard of guest/users

Tags: wordpress

I want to disable/hide the contact option which is provided by contact form 7 plugin and the comment option from the dashboard of user/guest's. Is there any process?
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ILA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for a **User role system**, in which you have to use a plugin for that and set permissions for specific roles.

1. There is a good plugin for that which is free [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) and for more details, that how you can set up this plugin please visit this post [GreenGeeks](https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/hide-admin-menu-items-for-specific-users-in-wordpress/)
2. There is one more plugin [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)